# question regarding Stern-Gerlach experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

When Stern-Gerlach experiment was done with quantum electron , two peaks were observed rather than a continuous distribution as in case of small magnets , but how did those peaks confirm that angular momentum is quantized ??

Comment: Well, they saw two, and only two. Kind of ‘quantized’ by definition.

Comment: It was not done with a single electron but with an atom (Ag) that has a single unpaired electron.

Comment: Somewhat late commenting, but: you might be interested in https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/physics-experiment/app5.html